# Bing Search API sometimes returns: myscript.js:109 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined

Tags: javascript, bing, bing-api

I have a demo app that uses the Bing Search API to return search results.

https://codepen.io/Teeke/pen/JLadEz

A successful search query returns:

```
XHR finished loading: GET "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/search?q=learn%20javascript&mkt=en-GB&SafeSearch=strict&count=25&offset=0&textDecorations=true&textFormat=HTML".
```

Sometimes a search query will open up a new browser window, and return 'undefined'. The console returns:

```
myscript.js:109 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined
    at showDiv (myscript.js:109)
    at bingWebSearch (myscript.js:322)
    at HTMLFormElement.onsubmit ((index):26)
showDiv @   myscript.js:109
bingWebSearch   @   myscript.js:322
onsubmit    @   (index):26
```

Why do searches sometimes not work?  Is it because the trial API is rate limited?

Comment: Seems you are not getting error from the Bing Web Search API, you are getting it while parsing the json response. If you are getting from the API itself, could you please provide the error code?

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'll check and get back to you in a couple of days.